# Netbeans: Unexpected Exception

Tags: java, exception, netbeans

I installed Apache Netbeans on my PC. And everything worked fine. But the next day i wanted to go on with my work, but since then i am getting all the time an exception:

```
A java.lang.IllegalAccessError exception has occurred.
Please report this at https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NETBEANS/issues,
including a copy of your messages.log file as an attachment.
The messages.log file is located in your 
C:\Users\svent\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\12.0\var\log folder.
```

**I have the follwoing settings:**

Product version: Apache NetBeans IDE 12.0

Java: 17; OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 17+35-2724

System: Windows 10 amd64

I have tried to uninstall everything and install it again. I also tried out to use Java 11 or Java 14. I also have tried to delete the 12.0 folder from netbeans in the AppData. But none of this helped.

Here is the exact Exeption:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: superclass access check failed: class org.netbeans.lib.nbjavac.services.CancelAbort (in unnamed module @0x6a51d5d0) cannot access class com.sun.tools.javac.util.Abort (in module jdk.compiler) because module jdk.compiler does not export com.sun.tools.javac.util to unnamed module @0x6a51d5d0
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
    at org.netbeans.JarClassLoader.doLoadClass(JarClassLoader.java:287)
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.selfLoadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:246)
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.doFindClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:174)
    at org.netbeans.ProxyClassLoader.loadClass(ProxyClassLoader.java:125)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.parsing.JavacParserFactory.createPrivateParser(JavacParserFactory.java:79)
    at org.netbeans.api.java.source.JavaSource$JavaSourceAccessorImpl.createCompilationController(JavaSource.java:739)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.source.JavaSourceUtilImpl.getModuleInfoHandle(JavaSourceUtilImpl.java:271)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.preprocessorbridge.spi.JavaSourceUtilImpl$MyAccessor.getModuleInfoHandle(JavaSourceUtilImpl.java:119)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.preprocessorbridge.api.ModuleUtilities.init(ModuleUtilities.java:122)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.preprocessorbridge.api.ModuleUtilities.resolveModule(ModuleUtilities.java:104)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.api.common.classpath.ModuleClassPaths$ModuleInfoClassPathImplementation.getResources(ModuleClassPaths.java:882)
    at org.netbeans.api.java.classpath.ClassPath.entries(ClassPath.java:363)
    at org.netbeans.spi.java.classpath.support.MuxClassPathImplementation.getResources(MuxClassPathImplementation.java:90)
    at org.netbeans.api.java.classpath.ClassPath$SPIListener.propertyChange(ClassPath.java:1343)
    at org.openide.util.WeakListenerImpl$PropertyChange.propertyChange(WeakListenerImpl.java:190)
    at java.desktop/java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeSupport.java:343)
    at java.desktop/java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:335)
    at java.desktop/java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:268)
    at org.netbeans.spi.java.classpath.support.MuxClassPathImplementation.propertyChange(MuxClassPathImplementation.java:127)
    at org.openide.util.WeakListenerImpl$PropertyChange.propertyChange(WeakListenerImpl.java:190)
    at java.desktop/java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeSupport.java:343)
    at java.desktop/java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:335)
    at java.desktop/java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:268)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.api.common.classpath.ClassPathProviderImpl$SourceLevelSelector.propertyChange(ClassPathProviderImpl.java:1575)
    at org.openide.util.WeakListenerImpl$PropertyChange.propertyChange(WeakListenerImpl.java:190)
    at java.desktop/java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.fire(PropertyChangeSupport.java:343)
    at java.desktop/java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport.firePropertyChange(PropertyChangeSupport.java:335)
    at org.netbeans.spi.project.support.ant.SequentialPropertyEvaluator.stateChanged(SequentialPropertyEvaluator.java:185)
    at org.openide.util.WeakListenerImpl$Change.stateChanged(WeakListenerImpl.java:331)
    at org.openide.util.ChangeSupport.fireChange(ChangeSupport.java:108)
    at org.openide.util.ChangeSupport.fireChange(ChangeSupport.java:94)
    at org.netbeans.spi.project.support.ant.ProjectProperties$PP$2.run(ProjectProperties.java:365)
    at org.netbeans.spi.project.support.ant.ProjectProperties$PP$2.run(ProjectProperties.java:363)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.DefaultMutexImplementation.readAccess(DefaultMutexImplementation.java:188)
    at org.openide.util.Mutex.readAccess(Mutex.java:193)
    at org.netbeans.spi.project.support.ant.ProjectProperties$PP.fireChange(ProjectProperties.java:371)
    at org.netbeans.spi.project.support.ant.ProjectProperties$PP.put(ProjectProperties.java:225)
    at org.netbeans.spi.project.support.ant.ProjectProperties.putProperties(ProjectProperties.java:107)
    at org.netbeans.spi.project.support.ant.AntProjectHelper$6.run(AntProjectHelper.java:740)
    at org.netbeans.spi.project.support.ant.AntProjectHelper$6.run(AntProjectHelper.java:738)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.DefaultMutexImplementation.writeAccess(DefaultMutexImplementation.java:229)
    at org.openide.util.Mutex.writeAccess(Mutex.java:246)
    at org.netbeans.spi.project.support.ant.AntProjectHelper.putProperties(AntProjectHelper.java:738)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seproject.api.J2SEProjectBuilder.createProject(J2SEProjectBuilder.java:579)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seproject.api.J2SEProjectBuilder.lambda$build$0(J2SEProjectBuilder.java:312)
    at org.openide.filesystems.EventControl.runAtomicAction(EventControl.java:102)
    at org.openide.filesystems.FileSystem.runAtomicAction(FileSystem.java:494)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seproject.api.J2SEProjectBuilder.build(J2SEProjectBuilder.java:310)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seproject.J2SEProjectGenerator.createProject(J2SEProjectGenerator.java:59)
    at org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seproject.ui.wizards.NewJ2SEProjectWizardIterator.instantiate(NewJ2SEProjectWizardIterator.java:187)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard$InstantiatingIteratorBridge.instantiate(TemplateWizard.java:1048)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard.handleInstantiate(TemplateWizard.java:602)
    at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.NewProjectWizard.handleInstantiate(NewProjectWizard.java:51)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard.instantiateNewObjects(TemplateWizard.java:436)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizardIterImpl.instantiate(TemplateWizardIterImpl.java:228)
    at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizardIteratorWrapper$ProgressInstantiatingIterator.instantiate(TemplateWizardIteratorWrapper.java:155)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.callInstantiateOpen(WizardDescriptor.java:1602)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.callInstantiate(WizardDescriptor.java:1546)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.access$2300(WizardDescriptor.java:67)
    at org.openide.WizardDescriptor$Listener$2$1.run(WizardDescriptor.java:2233)
    at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1418)
    at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.GlobalLookup.execute(GlobalLookup.java:45)
    at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:278)
[catch] at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2033)
```

I hope someone can help me with this, because i don't know what to do anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running NetBeans 12.0 with JDK 17. This is not a supported combination.

You have two options:

- Stick with NetBeans 12.0, and use JDK 14 instead.
- Stick with JDK 17, and use NetBeans 12.5 instead. (In this case you don't need to uninstall NetBeans 12.0 first.)

See the release notes for [NetBeans 12.0](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb120/nb120.html) and [NetBeans 12.5](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb125/nb125.html) for details on which versions of Java are supported.

Questions similar to this one are common here, and it's unfortunate that NetBeans doesn't do a better job of proactively preventing unsupported JDKs from being used. That said, in NetBeans defense:

- The error message you posted was explicitly referring you to the NetBeans log file (`messages.log`) for further information.
- The NetBeans Release Notes always explicitly state which versions of Java are supported for a given NetBeans release, and no assumptions should be made. For example, in the case of NetBeans 12.5 the supported releases are ["JDK LTS releases 8 and 11, with experimental support for JDK 17"](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb125/nb125.html). That information is important, because it shows that although JDK 17 has "experimental support", releases JDK 12 through JDK 16 are not supported.

Comment: Now I installed NetBeans 12.5 and it works again! Perfect! Thanks!